Can you export shapekeys without the mesh in GLB?
I am exporting shapekeys and animation data from Blender to GLB format. However, the shapekeys are dependent on the mesh, causing the GLB file size to become too large.
Is there a way to export only the shapekeys in the GLB format without the mesh?

That is like trying to sell toast but without the bread. I doubt that is possible
